Round the corners of Google column chart area
Code snippet for getting the output:
Google column chart has been used. Not able to round the corners of the chart area.


google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(fetchJSONData);

// Set Data
function fetchJSONData() {
  fetch("./data.json")
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data[0].amount);
      var datavis = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      datavis.addColumn("string", "Day");
      datavis.addColumn("number", "Amount");
      datavis.addColumn({
        role: "tooltip",
        p: { html: true },
      });
      datavis.addColumn({ type: "string", role: "style" });
      var len = data.length;
      //console.log("length of array:" + len);
      //datavis.addRows(len);
      const d = new Date();
      let day = d.getDay();
      if (day === 0) day = 6;
      else day = day - 1;
      //console.log("day" + d);
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i === day)
          datavis.addRow([
            data[i].day,
            data[i].amount,
            "$" + data[i].amount,
            "color:#76B5BC",
          ]);
        else
          datavis.addRow([
            data[i].day,
            data[i].amount,
            "$" + data[i].amount,
            "",
          ]);
        // datavis.setValue(i, 0, data[i].day);
        // datavis.setValue(i, 1, data[i].amount);
      }
      //var datavis = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      // ["Country", "Mhl", { role: "tooltip", p: { html: true } }],
      // ["Italy", 54.8, "54.8T"],
      // ["France", 48.6, "54.8T"],
      // ["Spain", 44.4, "54.8T"],
      // ["USA", 23.9, "54.8T"],
      // ["Argentina", 14.5, "54.8T"],
      //]);

      // Set Options
      var chartColor = "#ec775f";
      var options = {
        title: "Spending - Last 7 days",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFAF5",

        titleTextStyle: {
          color: "#382314",
          fontName: "DM Sans",
          fontSize: 18,
        },
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        allowHtml: true,
        vAxis: {
          textPosition: "none",
          baselineColor: "none",
          gridlines: { count: 0 },
        },
        hAxis: {
          textStyle: { color: "#93867B", fontName: "DM Sans" },
        },
        legend: { position: "none" },
        colors: [chartColor],
      };

      // Draw

      var container = document.getElementById("columnchart_material");
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "ready",
        changeBorderRadius
      );

      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "select",
        changeBorderRadius
      );
      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "onmouseover",
        chartMouseOver
      );
      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        "onmouseout",
        chartMouseOut
      );
      chart.draw(datavis, options);

      function changeBorderRadius() {
        chartColumns = container.getElementsByTagName("rect");
        //console.log("chart column" + chartColumns);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartColumns, function (column) {
          column.setAttribute("rx", 5);
          column.setAttribute("ry", 5);
          column.setAttribute("stroke", "none");
          column.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);
        });
      }

      function setBarOpacity(index, opacity) {
        var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
          document.getElementById("columnchart_material")
        );
        // filter bars by fill color
        var chartBars = chart1
          .getContainer()
          .querySelectorAll(
            'rect[fill="' + "#ec775f" + '"],rect[fill="' + "#76b5bc" + '"]'
          );

        // console.log("chartBars" + chartBars[index]);
        // chartBars[index].setAttribute("stroke", "none");
        //chartBars[index].setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);
        // set opacity on index provided
        chartBars[index].setAttribute("opacity", opacity);
      }

      function chartMouseOver(sender) {
        changeBorderRadius();
        // set opacity to 0.5

        setBarOpacity(sender.row, 0.8);
      }

      // chart mouseout event
      function chartMouseOut(sender) {
        // set opacity to 1

        changeBorderRadius();
        setBarOpacity(sender.row, 1);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Unable to fetch data:", error));
}

//console.log("expdata:" + data[0].amount);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,9..40,100..1000;1,9..40,100..1000&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Sedan:ital@0;1&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Expenses chart component</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <style>
      .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        color: "#fffaf5";
      }

      .attribution {
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .attribution a {
        color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
      }

      .google-visualization-tooltip {
        color: white !important;
        background-color: rgb(11, 11, 11) !important;
        font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif !important;
        border-radius: 18% !important;
        padding: 0.3% 0.3% 0.3% 0.3% !important;
        align-content: center !important;
        margin-left: -9% !important;
        border: none !important;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="./expensechart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div
        class="topbox"
        style="background-color: #ec775f; width: 700px; border-radius: 15px"
      >
        <p>My balance</p>
        <p>$921.48</p>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div
        id="columnchart_material"
        style="width: 700px; height: 400px; padding-left: 0.1%"
      ></div>
      <br />
      <div>Total this month $478.33 +2.4% from last month</div>

      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by
        <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
          >Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Aparna Gopalakrishnan</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



**What options or code can be written to round the corners of a google chart area? **
I am a beginner in Javascript coding.
Below is the output from the code

`

the chart area (light orange color) is rounded in the expected output.

Hi Aparna. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem. Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance. Best wishes.

Sorry if my question was not clear enough. I have figured a way to fix the problem myself outside of the chart.

I have come up with a solution for the problem by adding the required CSS properties to the div element containing the chart.
<div class="chart" **style="background-color: #fffaf5; border-radius: 10px"**>
  <div id="columnchart_material"></div>
  <hr / style="color:#93867B ;width: 85%; opacity: 0.2;height:
  1px;background-color: #93867B;">
  <br />
  <div id="total">
    <div id="totcol1" style="padding-left: 5%">
      <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #93867b"
        >Total this month</span
      >
      <div>
        <span
          style="color: #382314; font-weight: bold; font-size: xx-large"
          >$478.33</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="totcol2" style="margin-left: auto; padding-right: 5%">
      <br />
      <span style="color: #382314; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px"
        >+2.4%</span
      >
      <div>
        <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #93867b"
          >from last month</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>

